# HTML Hide input/post name

Tags: html

Im looking to hide a post request name from the user, So they cannot post to a URL.

For example, Im looking for something that will avoid users checking the post request name and sending something to bypass the restrictions to insert into a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the POST request comes from the user's browser, then they can inspect it. There is no way to avoid that.

Your only option is to make the POST request from somewhere else (such as your server). There is a good chance that you won't be able to do that (due to dependencies on the request coming from the user or included data they supply).

You mention "restrictions". If those restrictions are currently enforced with client side code: Enforce them with server side code.

Comment: Why not? - Really sorry for the unclear post @Quentin

Comment: @Segeco — Because the browser runs on the user's computer which is under the user's control (unlike the server which is under your control).